# Boost asio async_write callback doesn't get called

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm trying to write a simple server to send messages asynchronously, but my callback for async_write doesn't get called. By the way, data is succesfully transmitted to the client.

Firs, my server initialisation code:

```
void Server::start()
{
    ioService = new boost::asio::io_service();
    acceptor = new tcp::acceptor(*ioService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));

    serverRunning = true;

    serverThread = new boost::thread(&Server::run, this);
    startAccept();
}
```

My start accept and accept handler methods:

```
void Server::startAccept()
{
    serverSocket = new tcp::socket(acceptor->get_io_service());

    acceptor->async_accept(*serverSocket,
        boost::bind(&Server::handleAccept, shared_from_this(),
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void Server::handleAccept( const boost::system::error_code& error )
{
    changeState(Connected);
}
```

The handleAccept method get called when i connect, the changeState method does nothing for now. After the client connected, i put some data to the `toSend` vector, and the server's thread sends them:

```
void Server::run(){
    while( serverRunning ){
        ioService->poll();

        if (toSend.size()>0 ){
            mtx.lock();
            for (int i=0; i<toSend.size(); i++){
              cout << "async write" << endl;
                boost::asio::async_write(*serverSocket, boost::asio::buffer(toSend.at(i)),
                        boost::bind(&Server::handleSend, shared_from_this(),
                            toSend.at(i),
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
            }
            toSend.clear();
            mtx.unlock();
        }
        usleep(1000);
    }
}
```

I can see "async write" messages coming on std out, and the client recieves the data as well. My handleSend method is just some cout now, but it never get called. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to `poll` the `io_service` manually, do this *after* it gets some work, and call `reset` [between the iterations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html).

Besides, do not call `asio::async_write` in a loop - the data won't arrive in the correct order. Instead, either prepare a single sequence of buffers and send it at once, or chain `async_write` - completion handler - `async_write`, as shown in the examples.

Comment: Why can't you call async_write in a loop? The asynchronous posts are done FIFO.

Comment: @ Michael Mueller The FIFO of posts (which is, by the way, implementation detail) is irrelevant here. Note that `asio::async_write` is a [composed operation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload2.html) implemented in terms of multiple calls to stream's async_write_some(). If one calls `async_write` in a loop, the chains of `async_write_some` calls get interleaved.

Comment: R Since async_write is a composed operation, the completion handler is invoked upon successful write, meaning that the other end has sent a corresponding ACK for the data. This is problematic for larger messages which are composed of more than one async_write_some operations, as there is no way to keep the send buffers on the hardware devices full. Is there any way, then, to eliminate the inevitable delay between individual async_write_some calls, or do we just have to accept this as part of the design?

Comment: @Michael Mueller There no way to call async_write_some before the previous one completed. But why are you concerned with that? Does you benchmark show that you don't reach the maximal possible throughput?

Comment: @Michael Mueller By the way, I'm not sure your statement is correct: most likely, the completion handler gets called when the data have been sent by the TCP stack. Note also, that the way the data is sent is platform-specific, and even configuration-specific (eg. on Windows one can request IOCP operation with or without buffering).

Comment: @ Igor R Yes, I have data that confirms that one async_write means one round trip between endpoints. On Windows, the completion handler gets called as soon as enough data has been ACK'd, not when it was posted to the hardware device. For Windows, we can call async_write as long as the data isn't going to be chunked under the covers by ASIO, but you need to be super careful. Generally, it makes sense to have one send outstanding. Using the multiple-buffer call DOES improve performance, but you still pay with a delay from latency.